# Excel worksheet maximum of calculated value

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Is there a worksheet function that enables you to find the maximum value of a series of calculations.  I'm trying to find the highest difference between two columns without creating a new column with the difference in.  I could use =max(l1-m1,l2-m2,l3-m3) etc. but there are hundreds of rows.  Max(l1-m1:l100-m100) doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(L1:L100)*ISNUMBER(M1:M100),ABS(L1:L100-M1:M100),""))`

Its an array formula, so commit the formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If your data is consistent you can even use:

`=MAX(ABS(L1:L100-M1:M100))`

Again this is an array formula.

Got this from [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174135).

Comment: Yes having an option to ignore any empty cells or text is good otherwise it could treat empty cells as zeroes and give the wrong answer.

Comment: @TomSharpe - Exactly, so the first formula will work for you.